# Creating private function inside directive

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to create a private function inside a directive? I need to do a rather complex process inside a directive to fill the directive's template.

Something like this (HTML):

```
<textarea the-result="data">
</textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
angular
.module("MyModule")
.directive("theResult", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            theResult: "="
            // calculatestuff = function(d){ // ... } can't put it here (error)
        },
        template: ' ... '
            + '{{calculatestuff(theResult.someproperties)}}'
            + ' ... '
    }
}])
```

Where can I put `calculatestuff`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notice that `directive(directiveName, directiveFunction)` uses only what `directiveFunction` returns. You can do whatever you want inside this function, like, for instance, define other function :

```
angular
.module("MyModule")
.directive("theResult", [function () {
    var calculateStuff = function (d) {
        // ...
    };

    return {
        // ...
    }
}]);
```

But of course, `calculateStuff` won't exist anymore during the `$digest` cycles and is not link to the scope, so you won't be able to call it inside your template. If this is really what you want to do, contemplate to put your function in the scope, during the linking phase :

```
angular
.module("MyModule")
.directive("theResult", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            theResult: "="
        },
        template: ' ... '
            + '{{calculatestuff(theResult.someproperties)}}'
            + ' ... ',
        link : function ($scope) {
            $scope.calculateStuff = function (d) {
                // ...
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

Since you use an isolated scope, this function won't be accesible from outside the directive.

Comment: After I moved the function to the scope within link, it works. Thanks!